# Fps drops when using .NETs ThreadPool

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine, threadpool

I have asked about this before, but didn't provide code because I didn't have an easy way to do so. However now I've started a new project in Unity and tried to replicate the behaviour without all the unnecessary baggage attached.

So this is my current setup:

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject calculatorPrefab;
    void Start ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(calculatorPrefab);
        }
    }
}

public class Calculator : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoCalculations);
    }

    void DoCalculations(object o)
    {
            // Just doing some pointless calculations so the thread actually has something to do.
            float result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                    // Note that the loop count doesn't seem to matter at all, other than taking longer.
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 1000; i2++)
                    {
                            result = i * i2 * Mathf.Sqrt(i * i2 + 59);
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Both scripts are attached to GameObjects. The 'Main' script is on a GameObject thats placed in the scene and is supposed to create a bunch of other GameObjects at start up which then in turn queue some random calculations for the ThreadPool. Obviously this produces a fairly big CPU spike at start up, but that's not the problem. The problem is that the main thread seems to be blocked by this. In other words, it produces horrible fps. Why is that ? Isn't it supposed to run in the background ? Isn't the whole point behind this not to make the main thread unresponsive ?

I'm really struggling to figure out what I'm doing wrong, because as far as I see it, it doesn't get much simpler than this.

Comment: 'I have asked about this before', adding the link to your original question would make it easier for people to check that out as well.

Comment: I would like some more information: 1) which unity version are you using?  2) Your calculator prefab, what is it? and what else does it have attached to it?

Comment: Version is  5.0.1f1 and what I posted here is all there is in the project. The prefab is just an empty object with the script attached.

Comment: "I've started a new project in Unity and tried to replicate the behaviour without all the unnecessary baggage attached" that is remarkably different from other people asking questions with Unity tag. I wish more people did that.

Comment: What does Activity monitor or it's windows equivalent say? Does this issue reproduce in a standalone build? In a mobile build?

Comment: I really can't tell you if it's different in a standalone build right now, haven't tested it and can't currently build it. However I do know that the actualy project still had the issue in a standalone build, so I'd assume it would be the case here too. Also, since I have no idea what the "activity monitor" even is, I'm not sure what you are asking here. And even if I did, I currently can't test it. Will report later though.

Comment: Just build the whole thing and tested it. I've just thrown a cube into the scene and toggle its active property via update, as a quick way to visualize how it is running. And it's still terrible. I even reduced the amount of objects being created from 10000 to 100, while increasing the loop count so it still takes a while. No real difference.

Comment: **Design tip**:  Generally when there is alot of calculations that must be performed for many objects, instead of doing so in one frame, group them and spread them out over time.  So for 10,000 objects maybe have a batch size of 1000 or 100?  Source:  _Cities: Skylines_;  [This good book](http://www.amazon.com/Engine-Architecture-Second-Jason-Gregory/dp/1466560010/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1431047468&sr=1-1&keywords=game+engine) is useful too

Answer (score 0):

On the first frame you instantiate 10000 prefabs. That is quite a load for a single frame. On the second frame you initialize 10000 thread pools. That is quite a number of threads and I am sure you are running into some upfront initialization costs.

The background task is not that complex. I use background tasks for really long running operations. For instance web calls and long running calculations. I dont think your task really fits. In other words the upfront cost exceeds the cost of running your calculation.

Try using a coroutine instead to breakup your calculations and instantiations. I think that is a better solution for this particular background task.

**Edit** Ran some tests per the comments below.

- 10k instantiates took on average (median) 104 milliseconds. The editor had poor framerate and used about 15% of my I7 cpu capacity.
- 10k QueueUserWorkItem took on average (median) 23 milliseconds. The editor  locked up for multiple seconds. My cpu capacity had a wonderfull 99% capacity.

**Conclusion**
Queuing the worker thread has some cost, but not a lot. The problems are mainly with your instantiate. That, and why are we quing 1000 worker threads for such a simple calculation ?

Comment: Threads are inappropriate for long-running I/O bound operations. The preference is to use unthreaded asynchrony (such as the Task Async Pattern) for I/O bound operations.

Comment: @DanielMann Unity is tagged, which uses the 3.5 subset. TLP is unavailable.

Comment: @nVentimiglia _"On the second frame you initialize 10000 **thread pools**...That is quite a number of **threads**"_ - incorrect. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` merely queues jobs, there is no direct relationship to the number of jobs and the number of threads. _[You can queue as many thread pool requests as system memory allows. If there are more requests than thread pool threads, the additional requests remain queued until thread pool threads become available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx)_

Comment: @DanielMann _"The preference is to use unthreaded asynchrony (such as the Task Async Pattern) for I/O bound operations"_ - agreed for I/O  but **where** is the OP performing I/O bound operations that would benefit from I/O completion ports?  All I see is alot of **compute** statements such as `Math.Sqrt()` which arguably does not warrant conversion to `Task`s.   Compute has no use for IOCP

Comment: I really have to ask, did you gus actually read the initial post ? I clearly state that this is just test code to highlight the problem, it's not actually trying to do anything. As you can clearly see in the code I don't even use the computed values. Therefor the upfront cost (of which I'm aware) doesn't matter, since it's only a test. Also what Micky Duncan said.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following problems with your code.

1. You are creating far too many background jobs at once, 10,000 to be precise.  .NET won't run them all concurrently all the same but still is perhaps not the best way to go.  On my machine (8 logical cores) the initial max workers via `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads()` was 1023
2. Each job is rather complex.  The calculation of Sqrt is not cheap and no wonder takes so long
3. Unity has methods for updating and methods for drawing.  The problem here is that your jobs are ongoing and thus drags down everything including updating; drawing; and everything in between; rather than computation just happening during Update()

Taking your code and just running it in a stand-alone .NET app, it took **15 seconds** to complete **maxing out all 8 of my cores**.

However, changing

```
result = i * i2 * Mathf.Sqrt(i * i2 + 59)
```

...to:

```
result = i * i2 * i * i2 + 59;
```

...also maxed out all of my 8 cores as before but this time took 6 seconds.

You might ask, *"well you took away to sqrt, what is your point"*.  My point is I don't believe you realise *how* intensive a call Sqrt is particularly with this statement:

> And it's still terrible. I even reduced the amount of objects being created from 10000 to 100, while increasing the loop count so it still takes a while. No real difference

Furthermore, scheduling so many jobs, regardless of tech, purely to update game objects won't scale.  Game designers update in batches.

My suggestion:

### Design tip

Generally when there is alot of calculations that must be performed for many objects, instead of doing so in one frame, group them and spread them out over time. So for 10,000 objects maybe have a batch size of 1000 or 100? **Source**: *Cities: Skylines*;

### Tell me more

- [Game Engine Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466560010)

[image]

Image copyright respective owners

Comment: @Sentrigal As I said, one does not update 10,000 game objects per frame, using one thread or not, that is arguably poor game design and won't scale. I did mention elsewhere on this page as to the true nature of the number of threads actually being created. I recommend you read up more on `QueueUserWorkItem` and thread pools. I wish you well